# Ruby: how to add separator character to the last?

Tags: ruby

Example,

```
> arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
> arr.join('-')
=> "a-b-c"
```

Is there any function to attach one more separator to the last?

```
> arr.func('-')
=> "a-b-c-"
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can append it at the end of string arr.join("-")+"-"

Comment: @user944938, `arr.join('-') << '-'` avoids creating a temporary string.

Comment: `arr * '-' << '-'` :)

Comment: @fl00r, do you know if `arr * '-'` is sugar for `arr.join('-')`, or just equivalent?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, equivalent (alias) http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-2A

Comment: @CarySwoveland no, it is not an alias :) but it is equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no single function like that. You can just hack it like this:

```
arr.push('').join('-')
```

If you don't want to change the original array. dup it:

```
arr.dup.push('').join('-')
```

Comment: This actually changes the array, I believe that `(arr + '').join('-')` would be preferable

Comment: @UriAgassi you can't add string to array. But you can add array to array `arr + ['']`

Comment: @fl00r - you are right - my bad..

Comment: @sawa, in some cases array splatting could bring problems with a stack ;)

Comment: @sawa https://gist.github.com/fl00r/11192702

Comment: @Uri, my bad for +1 your bad.

Comment: @sawa, Ruby 2+ I believe ;)

Comment: @sawa, `puts *(1..2**20)`

Comment: @sawa gist example was for 1.9.3 (I am old-fashioned :D)

Comment: @fl00r I confirmed that your `puts *(1..2**20)` raises a stack level too deep error while `puts (1..2**20).to_a` does not. I didn't know that splat abuses stack. How does that work? ... If it is complicated, then never mind.

Comment: @fl00r How is your life at Easter Island?

Comment: @sawa actually I am from Moscow :). I believe that splatting is recursive operation so bigger array - deeper stack

Comment: Your page says you are in Easter Island from a few years ago :)

Comment: @sawa, ha, everybody lies

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually want a `join` in this case, you want a `reduce` (commonly referenced by it's alias, `inject`):

```
arr.reduce('') { |concat, entry| concat + entry + '-' }
```

There are, of course, plenty of other ways of making this work, but spelling it out is less clever, and therefore a lot easier to figure out when you come back to it later (or someone else has to work on it).

Comment: I like your solution, but `arr.join('-') << '-'` is not that hard to figure out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way (just sayin'):

```
arr.join.gsub(/./) { |c| c + '-' }
```

Still like

```
arr.join('-') << '-'
```

best for its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the array.

```
arr.map{|c| c.concat("-")}.join
```